# MS Word 2008 for Mac - repeatedly crashing

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, microsoft-word, crash

does anyone have hints on how to mitigate a problem I've been having on multiple Mac OSX Snow Leopard 10.6.x?

Basically Word keeps crashing as soon as I begin editing documents of a reasonable size, particularly when using the "track changes" functionality.

Any hint would be very helpful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this was just one one Mac and one installation I would say to remove the Preferences File and see if that fixes it, but you say it's on more than one Mac.

One of the most common reasons for Word crashing during use is a font conflict.

Use FontBook to look for duplicates and conflicts (with Word closed).  See if that clears up the issue.

Comment: Hi, I cleaned up the font dupes and rebooted but but I still get the crashes. I still haven't tried deleting the preference files but I don't know what will I loose... bibliography db, license?

Comment: Do you use Endnote?

Comment: no, I don't. Eventually I got the opportunity to update for 10€ and didn't have the problem any more (well, perhaps once...)